# In a Tag Info, shouldn’t the “history” link being labeled “full wiki history”?

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

Next to the “Edit Tag Info” button, which allows to edit both excerpt and full wiki texts, there’s to links to the version histories of both texts:

[image: screenshot of a tag wiki guidance and the buttons in question]

A “Tag Wiki” consists of a “tag wiki excerpt” as well as a “full tag wiki”. While the rightmost history link specifically says “excerpt history”, the other is merely labeled “history”, which apparently refers to the history of all the Tag Info (or at least something more than just the full tag wiki history).

It’s not easy to come up with a distinct label text, and it’s not very important at all, but the link text should probably be ajusted to be less ambiguous (next to its specific counterpart).